# How to resize images due to container width automatically server side/without CSS

Tags: plugins, images

Does anyone know how to resize the served images, so the image has a width due to the content containers width. I do not mean to resize the image via 100% width css, but instead resize the actual dimensions and size if the image itself.

For e.g.: An image in an article which has the dimensions of `400px × 300px`. But in the overview I only need `200px × 150px`. But I do not want to edit every part of my theme to do so, because there are a lot of different sizes. Is there any possibility that this works automatically?

Comment: Max, keep in mind that plugin recommendations are off topic - see [help/on-topic] for more info.

Comment: can also be a code snippet or functions.php-changement! But thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think what you ask for is impossible. As the CSS is rendered on the client/browser-side there is no way to know what the dimensions will be before you have sent the page to the browser and it parsed the CSS. You can use the code from kaiser to minimize the effort, but you'll still have to edit your theme.

Comment: but before the content is delivered to the user, the theme knows the size of the previous container from css. no way to tell the image these sizes and resize it upfront??

Comment: Max, you can see my answer below. The only way is to either _replace_ the image server side, _or_ replace it dynamically. The first one is what I've shown below. The later one would need _a different_ extension of that plugin that uses a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @max `the theme knows the size of the previous container from css` No, the theme means the PHP parser. And the PHP parser doesn't parse any CSS code. That's the job of the browser. You simply don't have that information at that point of time.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. I;m pretty sure you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist, and in the wrong way :)

Comment: It is for Loading Speed. some of my images are larger than they have to be, because of responsiveness and availability (same picture is taken for the article overview and the article itself).

Comment: Think about it- 20 visitors on your site, let's say 10 different screen sizes that trigger the resizing function. That's 10 extra images, 100% cpu, and most likely the page being served in 2-10 seconds to them because of that. Not only that it's absurd, but having any more than one thumbnail size is not worth it anymore. Today all browsers do HQ resize and images don't use that much bandwidth

Comment: @onetrickpony thats right. Did not thought about this. Thanks! So i maybe have to rescale the images to its 100% width and live with it :)

Comment: I would serve the original size, or at least larger thumbnails, and let the browser downscale them to half the size. This improves quality on high-dpi displays (google "optimize site for retina displays"). You can also use lazy-loading techniques to save bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

As things like this are often requested, I've written a plugin named ["Dynamic Image Resize"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize). It's basically a plugin, but, due to it's one-file approach, it can be used as mu-plugin or theme include without a problem. It's main purpose is to resize single images on demand to a given height/width.

These are the arguments the "Template Tag"/function and the shortcode take:

```
src      // ID or path
height   // New/resized height
width    // The resized width
classes  // custom classes for CSS targeting 
hwmarkup // Do you want the height="ABpx" width="ABpx" on the image tag?
```

Now you could simply set the `hwmarkup` to `true/yes/1/on` and it gets rid of the `img`-HTML tag `width/height`-attributes, so the browser will resize it to the container width automatically. You could as well go further and simply extend the class:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#120987) Resize Image to Container Width
 * Author:      Franz Josef Kaiser
 * Author URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 * Needs @link https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize
 */

class wpse120987ResizeImgToContainerWidth extends oxoDynamicImageResize
{
    /**
     * Set the Attributes
     * @param $atts
     */
    public function setAttributes( $atts )
    {
        $this->atts = wp_parse_args( $atts, array(
            'width' => $GLOBALS['content_width']
        ) );
    }
}

function dynamic_image_resize_extd( $atts )
{
    return new wpse120987ResizeImgToContainerWidth( $atts );
}

add_shortcode( 'dynamic_image', 'dynamic_image_resize_extd' );
```

Note please, that this isn't tested, but just a quick draft.

Comment: thanks. will try it out. as it might not be exactly what i am looking for, but lets give it a try. :)

Comment: @max Another [related answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83993/make-thumbnails-in-woocommerce-replace-the-main-image-instead-of-opening-fancybo/121111#121111) might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general no, the PHP code has no way to know what image sizes you use in the CSS as PHP is being executed first on the server and only after that the CSS is executed in the browser.

Only way that might work is if you specify all the image sizes in CSS but don't serve any images, and only a reference to their src via a data-xxxxxx attribute. After the page load you run some JS that for each image checks its CSS defined height and width and set the src of the img to a url which will dynamically generate the image in the required dimensions.

The biggest drawbacks with this approach is that images are starting to load only after the page had finished loading instead of in parallel, and that people that block JS will not see the images at all.

If the images are in the same proportions as in your question you might as well serve the bigger image and leave the scaling to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), e.g.,

```
add_image_size('article',  400, 300, /*crop=*/ true);
add_image_size('overview', 200, 150, /*crop=*/ true);

the_post_thumbnail('article');
```